# JavaScript. Why private function is overrided when creating new object?

Tags: javascript, object, intervals

Hello i have problem with objects and setInterval. It looks like variable is shared between all instances. Here is example code:

```
function intervals(objectName) {
    var interval;
    var name = objectName;

    this.makeInterval = function() {
        clearInterval(interval);
        interval = setInterval(function() { console.log('hello world'); }, 20000);
    };

    this.intervalIdToConsole = function() {
        console.log(name + ' interval ID: ' + interval);
    };

    this.stop = function() {
        stopInterval();
    };

    stopInterval = function() {
        console.log('Stopping ' + name + ' id: ' + interval);
        clearInterval(interval);
    };
}

var int1 = new intervals('object1');
var int2 = new intervals('object2');
int1.makeInterval();
int1.intervalIdToConsole();

int2.makeInterval();
int2.intervalIdToConsole();
console.log('-----------------');
int1.intervalIdToConsole();
int2.intervalIdToConsole();
console.log('-----------------');
int1.stop();
int2.stop();
```

When i run this code in web browser in output i get messages like this:

```
object1 interval ID: 5
object2 interval ID: 6
-----------------
object1 interval ID: 5
object2 interval ID: 6
-----------------
Stopping object2 id: 6
Stopping object2 id: 6
```

And here is my question. What i am doing wrong? Why stopInterval() in object2 is called on int1.stop()?

**EDIT**
Oh my god it works now. Thank you! For better understanding. If i declare variable without var statement then it's global variable?

Comment: you should add `var` before any local scope variable initialisation : `var stopInterval = ..`

Comment: you could always set `stopInterval` to be a function of the object by typing `this.stopInterval = function() {...`

Comment: Variables that are defined without the `var` keyword are implicit globals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `stopInterval` is a global variable and thus overwritten by the next assignment.

To prevent this declare the variable inside the `intervals` function scope with a `var` keyword or as a member of that function with `this.stopInterval = ...`.

Hint: Use strict mode to prevent accidential declaration of global variables: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode

Answer (score 1):

You just forget for `var`. This code is working:

```
function intervals(objectName) {
    var interval;
    var name = objectName;

    this.makeInterval = function() {
        clearInterval(interval);
        interval = setInterval(function() { console.log('hello world'); }, 20000);
    };

    this.intervalIdToConsole = function() {
        console.log(name + ' interval ID: ' + interval);
    };

    this.stop = function() {
        stopInterval();
    };

    var stopInterval = function() {
        console.log('Stopping ' + name + ' id: ' + interval);
        clearInterval(interval);
    };
}

var int1 = new intervals('object1');
var int2 = new intervals('object2');
int1.makeInterval();
int1.intervalIdToConsole();

int2.makeInterval();
int2.intervalIdToConsole();
console.log('-----------------');
int1.intervalIdToConsole();
int2.intervalIdToConsole();
console.log('-----------------');
int1.stop();
int2.stop();
```

I added `var` before `stopInterval`.

Output:

```
object1 interval ID: 1
object2 interval ID: 2
-----------------
object1 interval ID: 1
object2 interval ID: 2
-----------------
Stopping object1 id: 1
Stopping object2 id: 2
```